# Setting SMBIOSAssetTag in a WMIObject via Powershell without a utility

Tags: powershell, wmi

I'm working with a Lenovo Thinkpad and I'm trying to set the asset tag in Powershell without using Lenovo's WinAIA.exe utility due to restrictions at work (wouldn't be able to access Windows. We would be running everything before we got into Windows Setup via Powershell), and I'm not sure how to go about this. Essentially, the property "SMBIOSAssetTag" (from the WMI class win32_SystemEnclosure)  is ReadOnly, and I cannot get around this. I did triple check to make sure that Lenovo does not have its own namespace, and while using the Powershell Module "LenovoBIOS" I didn't see anything that could help me achieve this goal (unless I'm blind and totally missed it). Is there any way to go about this? I've also tried modifying the ReadOnly property of the SMBIOSAssetTag property, but I couldn't get that to work. I'd love any and all feedback. If there is any extra information needed, I'd be happy to help as well.

Comment: Access to the SMBIOSAssetTag field is bios-vendor specific, not all vendors provide any way of doing this. As far as I can tell, WinAIA is the only way to do this on Lenovo. Do you mean you need to set the tag during during deployment? Because you should be able to call WinAIA the same way you call a PowerShell script. Or you could possibly create a Windows Live USB and write the tag before provisioning.

Comment: Yea, at current we have a setup with a wraparound batch file which utilizes the WinAIA utility, but we were seeing if we could take it a step further. Looking like that won't be the case though, unfortunately. Thank you for the kind suggestion and knowledge though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. The property is defined as read-only in [the MOF spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-systemenclosure) by design.

You're talking about writing to the SMBIOS information, which is an operation specific to your motherboard's OEM. It's up to your OEM to determine the data structure and storage method of the SMBIOS information, and the [SMBIOS standard](https://www.dmtf.org/standards/smbios) does not provide a standard write method the same way that there is a standard read method.

Comment: Yea, I kind of figured that would be the case. I just figured I'd verify here before confirming that for myself. Thank you for the information though. Really shed some light on the matter!